# Sprites don't become lit when installing Universal RP package

Tags: unity, 2d, rendering, lighting

I want to implement 2D lights in Unity. So, I downloaded the **Universal RP** package from the Package Manager.

I created renderers as shown here, then I created a light object (Point Light 2D) in a new project.

[image]
[image]

What should happen: After this last step, the scene should become black.

What happened in my case: There scene is same as before plus a warning message popped up in the other project, and when I place any object from my game, only that object appears black.

> **WARNING:**
>
> *FlowerM_03 material was not upgraded. There's no upgrader to convert Unlit/Transparent shader to selected pipeline
> UnityEditor.Rendering.Universal.UniversalRenderPipelineMaterialUpgrader:UpgradeProjectMaterials() (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.4.1/Editor/UniversalRenderPipelineMaterialUpgrader.cs:25)*

[image]
[image]

Videos I took reference from:-

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkgGyO9VG54

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5l8vP90EvU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning message tells you that the package doesn't know how to automatically upgrade the materials that your existing sprites are using. So, it's up to you to change their material to the one you want.

If you have a sprite that's already behaving the way you want, take the material it's using and apply it to the others.

If not, you can create a new material and set its shader to `Universal Render Pipeline > 2D > Sprite-Lit-Default`

Then select each sprite that's not behaving, and set it to use this new material.

[This is covered about 4 minutes into one of the videos you linked](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkgGyO9VG54&t=4m0s), so please be sure you're making full use of the references available to you when troubleshooting problems in your game.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Note that this is covered in the videos you linked. Please be sure to thoroughly review your research sources in future.

Comment: Next time, I'll take care of this. Thank you sir!